# The topbar dropdown menu looks weird on some Area 51 pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, design, top-bar

At http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq, the top-bar dropdown looks weird:

[image]

Elsewhere on Area 51 (e.g. http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges), it looks normal:

[image]

This is happening on Chrome 34 / Windows 7.

Comment: I love CSS. I really do. (Reproduced; will fix in a bit.)

Comment: @AnnaLear: I hope with something like `.topbar-dialog ul li { margin: 0px }`, and not, say, `!important` rules (which are a pox and an abomination). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this. A fix will roll out in the next few minutes. :)